# IntelliJ Cannot find appropriate Android platform for API level

Tags: java, android, maven, intellij-idea

I have a problem with Android on IntelliJ (community 2017.1.1).
I have Android SDK API 18, I've downloaded the packages from SDK manager and made sure API 18 is the only one I've got. I've set my project JDK to 1.8 and Android SDK to the one I've got.
Unfortunately I am getting an error:
**Error when importing module 'androidclient': Cannot find appropriate Android platform for API level 18**
In my POM I have:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <sdk>
        <platform>${android.sdk.api.version}</platform>
      </sdk>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Where android.sdk.api.version variable is set to 18. 
I've looked through this site and searched in Google for a similar problem. I've found that this was fixed in the newest version of IntelliJ so I downloaded it but it did not help. I've set the SDK in the Project Structure -> modules for each module individually. Still nothing. I cleared cache in the IntelliJ. Somebody else fixed it by adding to POM the platform version but I've already had that set.
Strange thing is, I can start the GUI of the project and it seems to be working. I can also build the module (androidclient, which gives the error) by clicking maven install.
I am new to the project and am not sure if the error I am getting is really a problem or is it just something strange with the IntelliJ? Has anyone here seen something like this? I realize it's not fatal (as I can build the project) but it's bugging me (literally ;) ) so if anyone has any idea, I would be very grateful to know how to fix that.
Thank you.

Here is a screenshot of my SDK config:

[image: sdk]

Comment: Could you please add [the screenshot of the corresponding SDK configuration](http://i.imgur.com/noBAf4Z.png) in IntelliJ IDEA?